# How can I use a 'group by' (or similar) statement to aggregate a few specified rows?

Tags: sql, database, view, aggregate-functions, teradata

I have a **Teradata** table with the following structure

```
ID  VALUE
--  -----
03  300
05  200
08  900
```

I need to create a view on top of this table that will group a few specified IDs together and aggregate their values.

```
   ID      VALUE
---------  -----
03 and 05  500
08         900
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming ID is a character, otherwise you need to do some typecasts:

```
select
   case when id in ('03','05') then '03 and 05' else id end,
   sum(value)
from tab
group by 1
```